Compose - if navhost argument contains # then it is saved partially in SavedStateHandle
I have setup navigation with NavHost, passing data between screens happens via NamedNavArgument.
The API I have returns player names like "username#123123". the problem is that if this value is passed to navController then it only saves "username". Any way to pass whole value?
I could replace # with some other char, but this looks like a extra logic. what if # is just one of many other chars?
Here is full code in a single file
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            OversearchTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    App()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = HOME) {
            composable(HOME) {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(), onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("$PLAYER_STATS/name#123")
                }) {
                    Text(text = "go to next screen and pass value")
                }

            }
            composable(
                "$PLAYER_STATS/{$PLAYER_TAG}",
                arguments = listOf(navArgument(PLAYER_TAG) { type = NavType.StringType }),
            ) {
                val viewModel: PlayerStatsScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
                Text(text = viewModel.userId) // "name#123" is passed in navigate() call but this will display "name"
            }
        }
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class PlayerStatsScreenViewModel
@Inject
constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
    val userId: String = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle[PLAYER_TAG])

//    val state = MutableStateFlow(userId)
}


const val HOME = "home"
const val PLAYER_STATS = "playerStats"
const val PLAYER_TAG = "playerTag"


Navigation version 2.8.0-alpha08 has a new way of navigation via @Serializable objects.
More detailed explanations is here https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-compose-meet-type-safety-e081fb3cf2f8
In short define destinations as objects or data classes with arguments and pass it instead of String constants.
For example:
  // Define a home destination that doesn't take any arguments
  @Serializable
  object Home

  // Define a profile destination that takes an ID
  @Serializable
  data class Profile(val id: String)

  // Now define your NavHost using type safe objects
  NavHost(navController, startDestination = Home) {
      composable<Home> {
          HomeScreen(onNavigateToProfile = { id ->
              navController.navigate(Profile(id))
          })
      }
      composable<Profile> { backStackEntry ->
          val profile: Profile = backStackEntry.toRoute()
          ProfileScreen(profile)
      }
  }


